# Play Framework 2.2.2 with Hibernate Envers

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework, playframework-2.2, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to implement [Envers](http://envers.jboss.org/) in Play Framework 2.2.2. I read a lot of How-to's but it doesn't work. When I made some changes (save or update) to an Entity annotated with @Audited nothing changes in the database schema.

Here my changes:

build.sbt

```
name := "labor"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  javaJpa, // <-- added
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.30",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-envers" % "4.3.5.Final",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.5.Final", // <-- added
  cache
)     

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

application.conf

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/****?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=****
db.default.pass=****
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Supplier.java

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Cont;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;
import play.db.ebean.Model;

@Entity
@Audited
public class Supplier extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Audited
    public String companyName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Contact contact;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Address address;

    public Supplier(String companyName){
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    // -- Queries

    public static Model.Finder<Long,Supplier> find = new Model.Finder<Long,Supplier>(Long.class, Supplier.class);
}
```

Suppliers.java

```
package controllers;

import models.Country;
import models.Supplier;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.data.*;
import static play.data.Form.*;
import views.html.suppliers.*;

public class Suppliers extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render(Supplier.find.all()));
    }

    @Transactional
    public static Result addSupplier() {
        Form<Supplier> formSupplier = form(Supplier.class).bindFromRequest();
        System.out.print(formSupplier.data());
        if(formSupplier.hasErrors()){
            return badRequest(add.render(formSupplier));
        }
        Supplier supplier = formSupplier.get();
        supplier.address.save();
        supplier.contact.save();
        supplier.save();
        return redirect(routes.Suppliers.index());
    }

    @Transactional
    public static Result editSupplier(Long supplierId) {...}
}
```

I would be very appreciate, if someone could help me.

Best regards,
couda

// EDIT (1):

1. I removed the listeners from the application.conf
2. Added the javaJpa and hibernate-entitymanager to build.sbt
3. Added "db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS" to application.conf
4. Added persistence.xml like described in [JavaJPA](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJPA)
5. Added @Transactional to the methods (addSupplier / changeSupplier) of the controller Suppliers.

But it still doesn't work. First I got an error about the @Audited which was missing in the referred classes (Address / Contact). After fixing that the application worked fine, except that no further tables were added after editing the entities in the frontend.

What is wrong with that configuration?

Comment: You shouldn't have to setup the listeners manually - are you using the same version of Hibernate as of Envers?

Comment: Sorry for that question but, do I have to use the hibernate-entitymanager instead of the hibernate-jpa? I didn't changed anything for accessing the database except the instructions for the use of the mysql http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaDatabase.

Comment: Hi @adamw I made some changes after reading the How-To http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJPA. Could you please take again a look on my configuration? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I think that you should remove `ebean` when you use JPA / Hibernate.

Comment: Do you have hbm2dll=auto (does your schema auto-update), or did you otherwise generate the schema from Hibernate?